# "she is as entitled to A as she is to B" or "she is as much entitled to A as she is to B"?

Tags: comparison

Which one of the followings is the correct sentence?

1. > She is **as** entitled to A as she is to B
2. > She is **as much** entitled to A as she is to B

Answer (score 1):

As much needs a quantity

> When we want to make comparisons referring to quantity, we use as much as with uncountable nouns and as many as with plural nouns:[<sub>Cambridge</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-as)

---

> She is as entitled to a doctorate as she is to a post-doctorate
>
> She is entitled to as much money as her colleague

Comment: So "as much entitled to" is wrong? It is used frequently. For example see here: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+entitled+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20much%20entitled%20to%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would say it may be used  - Your ngram is from 1800-2000. Try this one: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+much+entitled+to%2C+as+entitled+to&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20much%20entitled%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20entitled%20to%3B%2Cc0